# Grease Pencil - How do I hide the system cursor?

Tags: grease-pencil

How do I hide the system cursor while sketching with Blender in Grease Pencil mode?

Answer (score 1):

Under the overlays tab (top right of the viewport screen) press the dropdown arrow and uncheck **3D cursor**